# validity of pharmaceutical patent in another country

Tags: international, foreign, pharmaceutical

If a pharmaceutical is patented in the US could it be produced and sold freely in another country?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is Yes. Patents are national rights.

If there is no patent in the other country, there is no restriction on the product there.  However, you could not import the product to a country (such as USA in this case)where there is a patent in force.